# Why does capsule in eloquent require setAsglobal() method in slim

Tags: php, twig, slim

Why capsule instance requires `setAsglobal()` method in slim
`capsule->setAsglobal();`?

See: https://github.com/illuminate/database

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the setup-up instructions state is optional, see [illuminate/database](https://github.com/illuminate/database):

> ```
> // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods...
> (optional) $capsule->setAsGlobal();
> ```

However, you have to set the [Connection](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Capsule/Manager.php#L74) as Global, so you can access anywhere in the Slim code.

Since you usually access the Capsule using `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` or as `DB` Facade (e.g. `use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;`)

```
$result = \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager::select('select * from users');
```

you have to set it as global (as also shown in the [Slim v3 Cookbook](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/database-eloquent.html)).

Otherwise, you could try to do the DB work within the scope where the capsule is actually created via the connection manager (or recreate/reconnect with the same settings) when needed.